# How to read line by line and also get input from keyboard?

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I have shell script like -

```
while read -r line;
do 
echo $line
done  < file.txt
```

That's working fine, but I need to prompt the user for input after each line read from the file.
I tried adding "read " but that's not working.

```
while read -r line;
do 
echo $line
#prompt user here
read input_user
done  < file.txt
```

Any thoughts? I'm open to using awk too.

Comment: thanks guys..your answers are working fine..Now i'm confused which one to chose(tick) a answer :D ..

Comment: You don't need the trailing semi-colon after the `while`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a different FD for the loop's `read`.

```
while read -u 4 -r line
do 
  echo $line
  #prompt user here
  read input_user
done 4< file.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `-u` option of `read` which specifies the file handle:

```
while read -u 9 -r line; do 
    echo $line
    read -p 'Press ENTER ' input_user
done  9<file.txt
```

The `-u 9` combined with the `9<file.txt` means that the reads in the `while` loop and "regular" `read` statements still come from standard input.

You can generally choose any file handle not already used - `0`, `1` and `2` are standard input, output and error respectively. I tend to start at `9` and work my way down as needed, depending on how many file handles I need to access at once.

Sample transcript:

```
pax$ ./qq.sh
line 1
Press ENTER <ENTER pressed>
line 2
Press ENTER <ENTER pressed>
line 3
Press ENTER <ENTER pressed>
line 4
Press ENTER <ENTER pressed>
pax$ _
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really mean **keyboard**,

```
while read -r line; do 
    echo $line
    #prompt user here
    read input_user </dev/tty
done <file.txt
```

will read from the attached terminal regardless of any redirections.